# Mail from a joomla website with own sensitivity label in outlook

Tags: joomla-3.4, emails

I need your help. Is there any way to code a function for a joomla website that has email sending option, that the emails will have sensitivity labels in outlook? The sensitivity labels are already defined by the company.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the POP3 protocol but I seem it is managed by Outlook, not by the protocol. Look at the RFC here : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1939